# Override dropdown list in AtTask

Tags: filtering, attask

Is it possible to override the dropdown list in AtTask to allow filtering?  I have used the "External Page" where I created a jsp with the filtering capabilities, but I would like to filter my drop down list, within AtTask, rather than using the iframe. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

To which drop down are you referring? Is this an interaction between an external page and AtTask core product?

If this is a question about an in product feature or enhancement I would recommend calling AtTask's customer support. They can help you in learning more about the product and answer any questions you may have about customizing AtTask to suite your needs.

If I misunderstood something please let me know.